# what to put for a menu item?

Tags: java, android, xml

I want to write a program that has a menu on the top and that menu has an item.
I want it when the user clicks on the item, one Dialog box appears, something like the code in this page:http://www.mkyong.com/android/android-custom-dialog-example/
but in this page there's a button instead of menu and an item on it.
for the lines
:

```
 final Context context;
    private Button button;
    button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonShowCustomDialog);
```

I wrote both

```
 final Context context;
    private Menuitem menuitem;
    menuitem = (MenuItem) findViewByID(R.id.addmenu1);
```

and this one:

```
final Context context;
   private Menu menu;
   menu = (Menu) findViewByID (R.id.addmenu1);
```

but i get "suppling wrong type of resource identifier"
What should i put here in this case?!

here is my addmenu1.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:id="@+id/add"
          android:icon="@drawable/plus"
          android:title="Adding"
          android:orderInCategory="100"
          android:showAsAction="always"
            />
</menu>
```

Answer (score 1):

For the menu and submenu

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
tools:context="com.example.MainActivity" >

<item
    android:id="@+id/menu_item_options"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_config"
    android:title="@string/action_settings"
    app:showAsAction="ifRoom">
    <menu>
        <item
            android:id="@+id/action_settings"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_config"
            android:orderInCategory="100"
            android:title="@string/action_settings"
            app:showAsAction="always"/>

    </menu>
</item>
```

And the event of submenu click is in the activity when you create the menu
Example:

```
@Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        int id = item.getItemId();
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            // showPoppup 
            return true;
        } 
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
```